# micronaut applying @Validation to inbound controller POJO(s) doesn't validate

Tags: java, bean-validation, micronaut

Given this controller method.

```
import io.micronaut.validation.Validated;
...

@Validated
@Get(value = "test{?page*}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
public HttpResponse<TransactionListResponseDto> get(
        PageDto page) {
    Sort sort = Pageable.from(page.getPage(), page.getSize(), sortFrom(page.getSort()));
    return HttpResponse.ok();
}
```

and the PageDto that looks like this.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
...

@Getter
@Setter
@Introspected
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PageDto {
    @Min(1)
    private int page = 1;
    private int size = 10;
    private String sort;
}
```

and the necessary validation includes in the gradle file.

```
implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:$micronautVersion"
implementation "io.micronaut.beanvalidation:micronaut-hibernate-validator:$micronautVersion"
```

I am expecting that controller method to validate the arguments, but it's very happy for me to pass in (for example) `-100` as the page number, despite the validation attributes.
Following the [documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.6/guide/index.html#beanValidation) and [advice](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/03/micronaut-mastery-binding-request-parameters-to-pojo/).

I have to conclude I am missing a build step or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the `page` parameter by `@Valid` annotation to instruct Micronaut to use nested validation:

```java
@Get(value = "test{?page*}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
public HttpResponse<TransactionListResponseDto> get(@Valid PageDto page) {
    ...
    return HttpResponse.ok();
}
```

Then it will behave like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/test?page=-100
{
  "message": "page.page: must be greater than or equal to 1",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/test?page=-100",
      "templated": false
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you have Micronaut Data in you project then you can use already existing `io.micronaut.data.model.Pageable` interface for pagination and pass it directly into repository classes. In that case your method can look like this:

```java
@Get(value = "test", produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
public HttpResponse<Page<ItemOverview>> get(@Valid Pageable pageable) {
    return HttpResponse.ok(someRepository.findAll(pageable))
}
```